# Como resolver esse erro de sintaxe em python?

Tags: python

Estou fazendo um código para captar ping em MS de diversos sites para teste de conexão e em uma das linhas (segue abaixo) está dando erro de sintaxe, já tentei corrigir e foi falho.

```
if myStats.maxTime destIP<.
```

Comment: Esse código não faz muito sentido. O que é `myStats`?

Comment: Uma variavel que armazena estatistica da rede(conexão/ping)

Comment: Certo, e como ela é definida? O que seria `destIP`?